# ¿Cómo tener múltiples formatos de fecha con MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito obtener una fecha y formatearla en múltiples idiomas en la misma consulta.

```sql
SELECT
id, created_at,
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d - %M - %Y')) AS "fecha-espanol",
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y/%M/%d')) AS "fecha-ingles",
from usuario;
```

Sé que para cambiar el idioma del `DATE_FORMAT` se tiene que hacer un `SET` a `lc_time_names`:

```sql
SET lc_time_names = 'en_US';
```

Cómo podría obtener los dos formatos de fecha (uno en inglés y otro en español) en la misma consulta si lo que deseo es algo como lo siguiente:

```
| id | created_at          | fecha_espanol       | fecha_ingles     |
|----|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
| 1  | 2020-02-14 11:32:08 | 14 - Febrero - 2020 | 2020/February/14 |
| 2  | 2020-02-15 11:32:08 | 15 - Febrero - 2020 | 2020/February/15 |
| 3  | 2020-02-16 11:32:08 | 16 - Febrero - 2020 | 2020/February/16 |
```

Comment: En tu consulta no deberías resolver problemas de la vista, es decir consulta para obtener la fecha solo has una, posterior al recuperar ese valor asignalo a variables y con tu le guaje de programación formatea, al menos yo veo poco mantenible y lógico lo que deseas

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu comentario! De hecho es justo algo que estoy considerando si es una o mala practica, aunque realmente por ahora mi duda es más si esto es algo posible de hacer o no.

Comment: Es posible hacerlo desde la consulta `SELECT`, pero como bien dice @Aprendiz, es mejor manejar eso en el contexto en que recibas los datos, pues de eso modo vas a estar trabajando con un set de datos más ligero, que trae una sola columna y luego con las funciones propias del lenguaje servirías las fechas en el formato que sea. En cuanto a la consulta, no necesitas sub-querys para esto, puedes hacerlo así, sin más: `SELECT
id, created_at, DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d - %M - %Y') AS "fecha-espanol", DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y/%M/%d') AS "fecha-ingles"
from usuario;`

Comment: Exactamente como dice @A.Cedano es mejor trabajarla desde la vista y formatear un solo valor para convertirlo al formato que vos quieras allí. E incluso el dia que quieras darle otro formato a la fecha no tiene que modificar tu consulta sino que puedes hacerlo de una manera mas simple desde la vista. Tu consulta va a ser siempre ligera.

Answer (score 0):

No hay una forma elegante de resolverlo desde el motor, como ya te habrás dado cuenta `SET lc_time_names = 'en_US';` actúa sobre la sesión completa. Lamentablemente, lo único que se me ocurre es pasar por una tabla de traducción, algo así:

```
create table nombre_meses (from_name varchar(15), to_name varchar(15), lang_to varchar(15));

insert into nombre_meses (from_name , to_name, lang_to) values ('January', 'Enero', 'es');
insert into nombre_meses (from_name , to_name, lang_to) values ('February', 'Febrero', 'es');
insert into nombre_meses (from_name , to_name, lang_to) values ('March', 'Marzo', 'es');
insert into nombre_meses (from_name , to_name, lang_to) values ('April', 'Abril', 'es');
insert into nombre_meses (from_name , to_name, lang_to) values ('May', 'Mayo', 'es');
insert into nombre_meses (from_name , to_name, lang_to) values ('June', 'Junio', 'es');
insert into nombre_meses (from_name , to_name, lang_to) values ('July', 'Julio', 'es');

-- Falta completar el resto de los meses
```

Luego, simplemente hay que hacer un `REPLACE()`:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'en_US';

SELECT REPLACE(DATE_FORMAT(now,'%d - %M - %Y'),
               MONTHNAME(now),
               M.to_name) AS "fecha-espanol",
       DATE_FORMAT(now,'%Y/%M/%d') AS "fecha-ingles"
       FROM ( SELECT CURDATE() AS now ) T
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT from_name,
                          to_name
                          FROM nombre_meses
                          WHERE lang_to = 'es'
                   ) M
                   ON MONTHNAME(now) = M.from_name
```

Comment: Creo que habría que anotar de forma bien visible que se opte por esto únicamente en el caso de que sea una exigencia infranqueable que deba hacerse desde el motor de base de datos, ya que si esto se puede hacer por programación es mejor hacerlo así y no vía base de datos.